# Template / generic way to use LINQ SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following class which is creating data access functions for Customers from my DB:

```
    public static Customer Get(int ID)
    {
        KezberPMDBDataContext db = new KezberPMDBDataContext();
        return (from p in db.Customers
               where p.CustomerID == ID
               select p).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static bool Remove(int ID)
    {
        Customer c = Get(ID);
        if (c != null)
        {
            KezberPMDBDataContext db = new KezberPMDBDataContext();
            db.Customers.DeleteOnSubmit(c);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I will be creating more classes, ex, Employees, that will need exactly the same functionality, just with the Employee class.

Is there some way I could avoid code duplication and use templates / generics in some way?

Thanks

Comment: Is it Linq to Sql or Entity Framework? If EF, then what version? In either case I suggest you to google on `implementing generic repository pattern`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntityFramework 4.3 and 5's [`DbSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679599%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) class has a [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.find%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method that does exactly what your `Get` method does, and a [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.remove%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method that does sort of what your `Remove` does (it accepts an object and not an id).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
 private T GetById(int id, IQueryable<T> list)
    {
        var itemParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");

        var whereExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
            (
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(
                    itemParameter,
                    PrimaryKeyName
                    ),
                Expression.Constant(id)
                ),
            new[] { itemParameter }
            );

        var item = list.Where(whereExpression).SingleOrDefault();

        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new PrimaryKeyNotFoundException(string.Format("No {0} with primary key {1} found",
                                                                typeof(T).FullName, id));
        }

        return item;
    }
```